# What is the cranberries/sugar ratio used in the American cranberry sauce?

Tags: sauce, sugar, cranberries

I once tried to make a cranberry sauce like the one I tasted on Long Island, but the one I made tasted differently (it was more sour). I guess I used less sugar that I should have done.

Do I wrongly recall, or do you use also lemon juice to prepare the American version of the cranberry sauce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 12 ounces of cranberries, use about 1 cup of sugar. You may like to use part brown sugar. Lemon juice, orange juice, or zest of either are welcome additions. There is no absolutely standard American version; like anything else, every cook has their own variation.

Comment: I like to add brown sugar, orange zest, and a few seived raspberries (to remove seeds) to mine.

Comment: Just thought I'd link to the Oceanspray recipe in a comment. I always reduce the sugar and just use lemon zest, no juice, personally, but I always considered the recipe on the back of the bag "standard" https://www.oceanspray.com/en/Recipes/By-Course/Sauces-Sides-and-Salads/Fresh-Cranberry-Sauce

Answer (score 2):

All fruits, including cranberries, will vary in sweet/tartness from crop to crop. Many variables will affect a crop, for instance, a drought will usually make smaller, sweeter fruits.

When cooking with fruits, always taste, then adjust the sugar to the sweetness you like.